# Error executing google cloud function in google cloud, but working fine in local

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to do sentiment analysis using tensorflow JS using a google cloud function. When I am executing it in my local, everything is working as expected, but when deploying it to google cloud I am getting the below error.

```
{"error":"Something went wrong. Please try again later.Error: GatherV2: the index value 32599 is not in [0, 19999]"}
```

First, "fetch" was a problem, I installed node-fetch and now fetch error is gone but still the function is responding with 500.

My git repo, README has the instructions:
https://github.com/arupsarkar/Retail-Demo-Cloud-Function

Thank you,

Comment: A possible issue is that you are using a different version of **TensorFlow.js** in your local environment and in Google Cloud Functions. Make sure that you are using the same version of **TensorFlow.js** in both environments, can you check if that's the case ?

Comment: I am deploying the function from my local to GCP and I verified the package.json in Google cloud after deployment it is the same as my local.

Comment: Confirmed my local and GCP has v 4.1.0 for tensorflow js version.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured out the error. I had to update the return object to a JSON or it could have been a string as well. You can see the changes in my github repo, however here is the change

```
  res.status(200).send(`{"score": ${score}}`);
```

Everything working as expected, initially I had for reference (see below) which was causing the error.

```
  res.status(200).send(score);
```